# What is the definition of a cross cap?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have looked this up in several places but can only find heuristic descriptions. What I'm after is a definition like

If X has certain properties, the cross cap on (of?) X is the quotient of Y with Z...

or something similarly precise.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean cross-cap as a subspace of an abstract 2-manifold (a Möbius band), or do you mean cross-cap as a geometric feature of a self-intersecting surface in 3-space, or do you mean something else?

Comment: As a subspace of a Mobius band I think. It states in my notes that $RP^2$ minus a disc is homeomorphic to a cross cap, and I was looking for an explicit definition (perhaps that is it...?)!

Comment: Then "cross-cap" is just a synonym for "Möbius band".  Both are  homeomorphic to $RP^2$ minus a disk.

Comment: Thanks - I understand now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, a cross-cap refers to the embedding of a Möbius band into 4-space created via a movie with the birth of a circle, a loop in the circle made by a type I move, a handle attached to sort-of turn the figure-8 inside out, and then removed the loop. This can be capped-off by a disk to embed the projective plane into 4-space. It can be drawn in a snap.

Comment: Is there a topological, rather than geometrical construction that one can do... I can't get my head around the geometrical one! Thanks!

Comment: No, sorry. Look at the variety of images on <a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=cross+cap&hl=en&sa=G&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ei=owGlT4vzHsi4iQfC2K2jAw&ved=0CGkQsAQ&biw=1109&bih=691> this page </a>, look at George Francis's "A Topological Picturebook," or my "How Surfaces Intersect in Space."